# How to integrate these integrals? $\int{\frac{1}{(x^x-x^{-x})}} dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

Problem :

$$\int{\frac{1}{(x^x-x^{-x})}} dx$$

I need answer about the following problem.
Please help . I will be grateful to you. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect that a closed form exists? WolframAlpha doesn't seem to return one.

Comment: I am very skeptical about a closed form of this integral. There is even no closed form for $\int x^x~dx$.

Comment: "*I need answer about the following problem.*" Do you? Surely this isn't homework, since every math teacher knows that this antiderivative [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions. Unless, of course, instead of $x^{\pm x}$ you meant $e^{\pm x}$, in which case the answer is $-\text{ arctanh}(e^x)$ , as can be shown by the simple substitution $t=e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$x^x - x^{-x} = x^x - \frac{1}{x^x}  = \frac{x^{2x}-1}{x^x}$$

And therefore your integral can be transformed to

$$\int \frac{x^x}{x^{2x}-1} dx $$

From here note we can perform partial fraction decomposition to yield

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \lbrace \frac{1}{x^x +1} + \frac{1}{x^x-1} \rbrace dx $$

Now the key is to integrate these little functions themselves which is a non elementary result but quite easy to approximate with series.

Comment: You will not find a closed form to this.